# Why won't PrintWriter Write to a Dynamically Created Text File

Tags: java, io, printwriter

So I'm making a game and trying to add a high score table that reads off of some data in a text file.  The text file is dynamically created if the user has never played the game before or the file does not already exist.  I can create this file successfully, but for some reason, PrintWriter won't write to the file.  Can someone please explain why?

```
//VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");  //Contains the current directory the program is located in.
File forTable = new File(currentDirectory + "\\highScoreTable.txt"); 
PrintWriter updateTable = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(forTable), true);

if(!forTable.exists()) 
{
    forTable.createNewFile(); 

    updateTable.println("Player\t\tScore");
    updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
    updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
    updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
    updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
    updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
 }

updateTable.close(); //Close the print writer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PrintWriter updateTable = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(forTable), true);

if(!forTable.exists())
```

It is impossible for this test to be true at this point. You just created the file, with `new FileWriter(...)`. It exists.

```
forTable.createNewFile();
```

It is too late for this, and you never need it in association with `new FileWriter(...)`. Constructing the `FileWriter` creates the file.

```
updateTable.println("Player\t\tScore");
updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
```

So none of this code ever got executed.

Answer (score -1):

When handling things that may cause an exception, always remember to use a try/catch statement. That was one problem.
After that, the file still doesn't write. What you had to do was place the printwriters writing call outside of the `!forTable.Exists()` part. Here's a revision of your code that works as intended.

```
String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");  //Contains the 
current directory the program is located in.
    File forTable = new File(currentDirectory + "\\highScoreTable.txt"); 

    System.out.println(currentDirectory);
    try {
        PrintWriter updateTable = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(forTable), true);

        if(!forTable.exists()) 
        {
            forTable.createNewFile(); 
        }

        updateTable.println("Player\t\tScore");
        updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
        updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
        updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
        updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");
        updateTable.println("-------\t\t--");



        updateTable.close(); //Close the print writer
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Both the `exists()` test and the `createNewFile()` are futile where they are, or indeed anywhere else.

Comment: @EJP But what if they were to use `BufferedWriter` for some whatever reason, would creating a new file be necessary by doing it my way?